# On Ubuntu ,implement container isolation(user namespace), more /proc/[pid]/gid_map and nothing output

Tags: c, linux, docker, ubuntu-16.04, linux-namespaces

when I study docker , the code in chapter: [user namespace] :
The meaning of the demo is to use [user namespace] to achieve :
Outside the container is the ordinary user permissions, in the container is root privileges.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>    // sudo apt install libcap-dev

#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

static char child_stack[STACK_SIZE];
char* const child_args[] = {
    "/bin/bash",
    NULL
};

void set_uid_map(pid_t pid, int inside_id, int outside_id, int length){
    char path[256];
    sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/uid_map", getpid());
    FILE* uid_map = fopen(path, "w");
    fprintf(uid_map, "%d %d %d", inside_id, outside_id, length);
    fclose(uid_map);
}

void set_gid_map(pid_t pid, int inside_id, int outside_id, int length){
    char path[256];
    sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/gid_map", getpid());
    FILE* gid_map = fopen(path, "w");
    //printf("*****gid---Pid: %d *****\n", getpid());
    fprintf(gid_map, "%d %d %d", inside_id, outside_id, length);
    fclose(gid_map);
}

int child_main(void* args){
    cap_t caps;
    printf("In the Child process !\n");
    //sethostname("NewNameSpace", 12);
    //cap_t caps;
    printf("*****Pid: %d *****\n", getpid());
    //set_uid_map(getpid(), 0, 1000, 1);
    set_gid_map(getpid(), 0, 1000, 1);
    set_uid_map(getpid(), 0, 1000, 1);
    printf("eUID = %ld; eGID = %ld; \n\n", (long)geteuid(), (long)getegid());
    caps = cap_get_proc();
    printf("capabilities: %s\n", cap_to_text(caps, NULL));
    execv(child_args[0], child_args);
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    printf("Start: \n");
    //int child_pid = clone(child_main, child_stack + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_NEWUSER | CLONE_NEWNET | CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_NEWPID | CLONE_NEWIPC | CLONE_NEWUTS | SIGCHLD, NULL);
    int child_pid = clone(child_main, child_stack + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_NEWUSER | SIGCHLD, NULL);
    waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
    printf("Already Exit \n");
    return 0;
}
```

On the docker book,eUID  = 0 and eGID = 0 , but my eGID = 65534
[more /proc/pid/gid_map nothing, but more uid_map is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31K04.png)

like this :

```
$ gcc userns.c -Wall -lcap -o userns.o && ./userns.o
```

and show :

```
Start: 
In the Child process !
*****Pid: 24072 *****
eUID = 0; eGID = 65534; 

capabilities: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,37+ep
```

when I input command in the child shell.

```
# more /proc/24590/uid_map
```

shows:          0       1000          1

```
# more /proc/24590/gid_map
```

show nothing

the key eUID and eGID should = 0 , but my eGID = 65534 .
I don't know why my eGID = 65534 , not = 0 ?

gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6 ubuntu1~16.04.4)

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Comment: #include <sys/capability.h>  need  sudo apt install libcap-dev